# How can I do this with a new and shiny typescript assertion function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have the following code:

```
type Robot = RobotOn | RobotOff;

class RobotOn {
    public readonly state = "on";

    public speak() {
        console.log("heyman!");
    }
}

class RobotOff {
    public readonly state = "off"
}

function maybeSpeak(robot: Robot) {
    if (robot.state === "off") throw Error("robot can't speak when it's off!");

    robot.speak();
}
```

Now I would love to assert the state of the robot with a typescript assertion function! So something like this:

```
function maybeSpeak(robot: Robot) {
    assertRobotState(robot, "on");

    robot.speak();
}
```

Is this even possible? And what would the `assertRobotState` function look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already have a look at the [TSdocs on assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) - they explain the concept pretty well imo. Just give me a note, if things are still unclear, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: yes checked it out! Was hoping that something could be done with generics maybe, but so far no luck. Also the docs are not really covering generic assertion functions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use assertion based on type of an argument - `asserts <<arg>> is <<type>>`.

```
function assertRobotStateOn(robot: Robot): asserts robot is RobotOn {
  if (robot.state !== 'on') {
    throw new Error('Robot is Off!');
  }
}
function assertRobotStateOff(robot: Robot): asserts robot is RobotOff {
   if (robot.state !== 'off') {
    throw new Error('Robot is On!');
  }
}
function maybeSpeak(robot: Robot) {
    assertRobotStateOn(robot);

    robot.speak();
}
maybeSpeak(new RobotOff());
```

References:

- [Typescript 3.7 Release Notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions)
- [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer's blog article](https://2ality.com/2020/06/type-guards-assertion-functions-typescript.html#assertion-functions)

Comment: Already figured that out! But could it also be possible to assert on an argument you pass to the assertion function? (like "on")

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer! It can be done with overloaded assertion functions! The following works:

```
type Robot = RobotOn | RobotOff;

class RobotOn {
    public readonly state = "on";

    public speak() {
        console.log("heyman!");
    }
}

class RobotOff {
    public readonly state = "off"
}

function maybeSpeak(robot: Robot) {
    assertRobotState(robot, "on");

    robot.speak();
}

function assertRobotState(robot: Robot, state: "on"): asserts robot is RobotOn;
function assertRobotState(robot: Robot, state: "off"): asserts robot is RobotOff;
function assertRobotState(robot: Robot, state: "on" | "off") {
    if (robot.state !== state) throw new Error("not cool");
}
```

Comment: of corse this could also be done with interfaces